# How to combine several regex search patterns into on pattern (i.e., use an addition operator) in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to combine input from a user as part of a regex search. Since I only want the user-provided pattern to be searched in particular lines, I want to combine (i.e., concatenate) the pattern provided with a pattern. What's the best way to do this in python?

Here is my code, which at the moment, doesn't work because an addition operator doesn't seem to be supported by re:

```
import re

q1=re.compile(r'^Organism.*')
q2=re.compile(r'(moth)')
q3=re.compile(r'.*</td>')


s="Organism: moth </td>"


test=re.search(q1+q2+q3,s).group(1)

print "test", test
```

Comment: In this case, I'd eventually want the user to provide q2...

Comment: I don't understand. Where is the user input part? Can you show what output you would like?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that part either, but I didn't want to complicate the question.

It presumably would be something like `q2=re.compile(raw_input("Enter organism you're looking for (e.g., r'(moth)')")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I know, a compiled regex object cannot changed once it's compiled.

Instead, you could delay the compilation until after the user input:

```
import re

q1 = r'^Organism.*('
q2 = raw_input("Enter organism (e.g., moth)")
q3 = r').*</td>'


s="Organism: moth </td>"

regex = re.compile(q1+q2+q3)
test = re.search(regex,s).group(1)

print "test", test
```

Comment: Do note that naively concatenating regexen could lead to problems with two adjacent metacharacters taking on an entirely new meaning (although I can't think of any actual examples off the top of my head).

Comment: Another potential problem might be that a malicious user could deliberately enter a very wonky string that causes the regex to run forever, freezing the program or returning bad results. Hopefully, that shouldn't be a problem, but I suppose you could always escape the user input.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the obvious way...

```
import re

q1 = "^Organism.*"
q2 = "(moth)"
q3 = ".*</td>"

rx = re.compile(q1 + q2 + q3)

s = "Organism: moth </td>"
test = rx.search(s).group(1)
```

In fact there's really no reason to compile a one-off regex, just use it as a string:

```
import re

q1 = "^Organism.*"
q2 = "(moth)"
q3 = ".*</td>"

s = "Organism: moth </td>"
test = re.search(q1 + q2 + q3, s).group(1)
```